# Responding to ACPI fixed feature button in Windows?

Tags: windows, acpi

My laptop's got a mysterious extra button on it that doesn't cause any keyboard messages -- I've verified this with a low-level keyboard hook.

It appears that it's an "ACPI Fixed Feature Button". Any ideas how I'd go about responding when it's pressed? I found some discussion of [how it works in kernel mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/doronh/archive/2006/09/08/746834.aspx). Does this information percolate up to user mode? Or do I have to write a filter driver?

Win32 or .NET solutions accepted. Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

Following URLs may be of interest to you.
[Vista ACPI Driver document](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/0/b/00bba048-35e6-4e5b-a3dc-36da83cbb0d1/ACPIDriver_Vista.doc) and [Vista ACPI Driver PPT](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/b/9/5b97017b-e28a-4bae-ba48-174cf47d23cd/CPA002_WH06.ppt)